# How to center modal with transition on material ui and make it responsive?

Tags: css, material-ui, responsive

I trying to use modal with transition using Material UI and have problem to centering it and also make it responsive or center in small size screen (mobile).

Modal can be centered and looks good on small size if not using transition, but if i add a transition, modal can't be centered or responsive.

This is the code modal without transition [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dj24rk).
Works good with large or small screen size.

This is the code modal with transition [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-i45q5z).

I tried to change the value of `top` & `left` but still can't get centered at the large and small screen size :

```
function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 25;
  const left = 25;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By default the modal creates a parent container that  uses flex, so in order to center you can comment your left: property that it is set to your modal,

```
return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    margin:'auto'
    // left: `${left}%`,
    // transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
```

and in your modal container you can align items with this

```
 <Modal
    ...
    style={{display:'flex',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}
  >
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1ny5g7?file=demo.js

Comment: Seems the parent container is default `display: block` now, so I had to also add `display: flex` to the modal for it to work.

Comment: is there any library | npm package that can get these feature done with much smooth and easy

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function getModalStyle() {
  return {
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
{
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: '100vw',
    maxHeight: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '50%',
    left: '0',
    transform: 'translate(0, -50%)',
    overflowY: 'auto'
}
```